# What does this mean ? >> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was curious what that meant in general.

But here is the specifics..

I'm doing a sortable jquery project, that touches this rails action :

```
def update_order
  params[:media].each_with_index do |id, index|
    media = @organization.media.find(id)
    media.do_not_touch = true
    media.update_attribute('position', index+1)
  end if params[:media]
  render :nothing => true
end
```

I'm just looking for a general reason why this error comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails [automatically checks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) for forged data when data is submitted.  From the doc:

> Protecting controller actions from
>   CSRF attacks by ensuring that all
>   forms are coming from the current web
>   application, not a forged link from
>   another site, is done by embedding a
>   token based on a random string stored
>   in the session (which an attacker
>   wouldn‘t know) in all forms and Ajax
>   requests generated by Rails and then
>   verifying the authenticity of that
>   token in the controller

You can disable this for the given Ajax call, or you could also send along a parameter named "authenticity_token" with the value of `<%= form_authenticity_token %>`

To disable it (which I would NOT recommend), you can do one of the following:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :update_order

  # you can disable csrf protection on controller-by-controller basis:
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal Rails form helpers will inject a hidden authenticity token into the form. When you roll your own, such as what you're probably doing for this Ajax code, you probably haven't added the token.

[This old post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/128970) has some good tips that may help you, depending on if you really care about using that token, or just want to turn it off for that action.